# Laravel if statement in query

Tags: php, laravel

I am beginner php developer.

I have this code:

```
Model::selectRaw('clients.*, if((client_company_infos.name != "" , client_company_infos.type == 1),  client_company_infos.name, concat(client_infos.first_name, " ", client_infos.last_name)) as name')
            ->leftJoin('client_company_infos', 'client_company_infos.client_id', '=', 'clients.id')
            ->leftJoin('client_infos', 'client_infos.client_id', '=', 'clients.id')
            ->get();
```

I have error:

> "message": "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near '== 1),  client_company_infos.name,
> concat(client_infos.first_name, " ", client_i' at line 1 (SQL:
> select clients.*, if((client_company_infos.name != "" ,
> client_company_infos.type == 1),  client_company_infos.name,
> concat(client_infos.first_name, " ", client_infos.last_name)) as
> name from `clients` left join `client_company_infos` on
> `client_company_infos`.`client_id` = `clients`.`id` left join
> `client_infos` on `client_infos`.`client_id` = `clients`.`id` where
> `clients`.`deleted_at` is null)",

When I make:

```
Model::selectRaw('clients.*, if(client_company_infos.name != "",  client_company_infos.name, concat(client_infos.first_name, " ", client_infos.last_name)) as name')
            ->leftJoin('client_company_infos', 'client_company_infos.client_id', '=', 'clients.id')
            ->leftJoin('client_infos', 'client_infos.client_id', '=', 'clients.id')
            ->get();
```

It's work fine. Problem. I with second if. How can I. repair it?

Please help me

Comment: The equal operator in MySQL is `=`, not `==`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no operator **`==`** in MySql.

You need to replace the condition with the following:

```
client_company_infos.type = 1
```